# angular 1.x ui-router can't navigate to routes other than default

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an **angular 1.5** app with **ui-router**.
i have configured the router like this:

```
$stateProvider
          .state('home', {
              url: '/home',
              controller: 'HomeController',
              templateUrl: 'components/home/home.html',
              controllerAs: 'vm'
          })
          .state('login', {
              url: '/login',
              controller: 'LoginController',
              templateUrl: 'components/login/login.html',
              controllerAs: 'vm'
          })
        .state('cb', {
            url: '/cb',
            controller: 'cbController',
            templateUrl: 'components/cb/cb.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        });
```

And added a default route:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

I have told to app to use html5 mode:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

And added the **base** element in the **head** section of my **index.html**

```
<base href="/">
```

When i browse to http://localhost:5000/ the router works fine and navigate to **home** changing the url to http://localhost:5000/home.
But when i try to navigate directly to `http://localhost:5000/home` i'm getting **404**.

The application is hosted in a visual studio web project in a folder (/app/index.html)

Any idea what i'm doing wrong ?
 
Thanks Gilad

Comment: What if you try to directly go to `http://localhost:5000/#/home`? `/home` could be treated by a "real" path on your server, where the `#` would mean that it's the root, and angular will take care of rendering your path.

Comment: It doesn't work. It keeps navigate to the default route

Comment: have you tried changing `.state('home', {})` to `.state('/home', {})` ?

Comment: Nope, but after i've tried i can tell it doesn't help.